# How do I iterate through each slicer item, but excluding those items with no data - In VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, slicers

I'm a vba newbie, so bear with me. 
2 things I am having difficulty with in my Excel VBA macro. 
(I am working with OLAP cubes)

(1) I am trying to iterate through items within a slicer - but don't want to iterate through items with no data. How do I accomplish this using VBA?

I am able to iterate through EVERY item in the slicer - but that's not what I want.

(2) how do I get the iteration to STOP once I reach the end of the list, so it does not become a never-ending loop?

Here's a piece of my code:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim slItem As SlicerItem
Dim slItem2 As SlicerItem
Dim sc3 As SlicerCache
Dim sc3L As SlicerCacheLevel

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

Set sc3 = wb.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Primary_Account_List_Combo__BI")

Set sc4 = wb.SlicerCaches("Slicer_TM_Hierarchy")
```

sc3L.CrossFilterType = xlSlicerCrossFilterHideButtonsWithNoData ''' new line of code to allow me to use .HasData

```
> ''' Select the first item within the slicer then iterate through them
> 
> ''' ensure the iteration is only done on items with data - Need to
> figure this out! Use the .HasData property


For Each slItem In sc3L.SlicerItems
If slItem.HasData Then   ''' This ensures the iteration is only on items with data 
sc3.ClearManualFilter


sc3.VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array(slItem.Name)

MsgBox (slItem.Value)
End If

Next
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sliceritem.hasdata

Comment: Michal Rosa  - Thank YOU for pointing me in the right direction! You hit the nail in the head! Both my issues were resolved :)